# PHP - Finding the difference between Two Multidimensional Arrays with different structures based on one value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am struggling with understanding what array function would work best for my particular situation.  There seems to be a vast amount of confusion from others as well as I have read several posts.

I have two arrays with different structures but both contain an ID field I would like to compare.

Array one is my footage array... it looks something like:

```
array(1) {
[0]=> array(5) { 
    ["ID"]=> string(3) "172" 
    ["Name"]=> string(26) "172_535A-New_Product-1.mp4" 
    ["Projects_ID"]=> string(2) "25"        
    ["FileName_Display"]=> string(18) "535A-New_Product-1" 
    ["FileName_Real"]=> string(22) "172_535A-New_Product-1"}}
```

In this array ID is what I want to compare.  The other array has a lot more information and is thus structured completely different BUT it also has this same ID listed as Footage_ID.  It looks something like:

```
array(1) { 
    [0]=> array(16) { 
         ["ID"]=> string(3) "168" 
         ["Unique_Array_ID"]=> string(1) "0" 
         ["HTML_ID"]=> string(15) "Item_0_0_34_A_0"         
         ["HTML_Selector"]=> string(10) "0_0_34_A_0"        
         ["Frame_Selector"]=> string(8) "0_0_34_A"      
         ["FootageArrayKey"]=> string(1) "0" 
         ["Timeline"]=> string(1) "0" 
         ["Tab"]=> string(1) "0" 
         ["inPoint"]=> string(12) "5.7919480000"        
         ["outPoint"]=> string(13) "43.2125420000"      
         ["Duration"]=> string(13) "45.1200000000"      
         ["Section"]=> string(1) "1" 
         ["Green_Screen"]=> string(1) "1"       
         ["Place_in_Timeline"]=> string(1) "0"      
         ["Footage_ID"]=> string(3) "172" 
         ["Projects_ID"]=> string(2) "25" 
}}
```

With these two the Footage_ID in array #2 (172) matches the ID in array #1 (172).  Therefore I do not need the entry from array #1.  I am looking for only IDs not listed in array #2.  This would be my return array.

First, since they are multidimensional I am a bit lost on comparing them.  Are there any built in functions for this like array_diff?  As far as I know array_diff is only for one dimensional array comparisons.  The fact that the arrays are different structures may mean little but to me it also seems like it could be an issue for certain functions.

The function I seem to need would accept three values($array1, $array2, $key_to_compare_by).  Then it would return the entries(arrays) from array1 where the $key_to_compare is not found.  I have not seen this situation in particular talked about yet and was wondering if anyone has advice on how to accomplish this.

I see people talking about filtering, mapping, and other functions but there are so many different approaches and none seem to be exactly what I am facing currently.  I giant part of this misunderstanding is that I DO NEED TO learn more about filtering, etc.  Any advice on this problem would be helpful.  Thanks!

Comment: The returned array should be elements of array #1 which doesn't exist(specific the id) in array #2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly you want to return entries from the first array if the `ID` doesn't exist as a `Footage_ID` in the second array.

If that's the case you can use `array_filter()` to check if each `ID` from the first array exists in the array of `Footage_ID`'s from the second, and if it doesn't, return the current array:

```
$o = array_filter($array1, function($a1) use ($array2) {
  return ! in_array($a1['ID'], array_column($array2, 'Footage_ID'));
});
```

#### [Here's a simplified demo](https://eval.in/799380)

Comment: This is what I chose to go with.  I am sure other answers here could work as well and I will come back to reread over this in the future for sure.  Thanks to everyone for all the suggestions!!!!

Answer (score 1):

The below uses a custom function.

Ok, i created 2 arrays :

`$mBigArray` : Let's suppose is the array with the big data (array #2) of yours.

`$mSmallArray` : Let's suppose is the array with the small data (array #1) of yours.

We just need a valid "ID" and "Footage_ID", the rest could be anything - dummy data.

```
$mBigArray = array(

    array(
        "id" => 1,
        "dummyData123" => "dummy",
        "dummyData5" => "dummy",
        "dummyData1" => "dummy",
        "dummyData494" => "dummy",
        "dummyData5" => "dummy",
        "dummyData3" => "dummy",
        "dummyData6" => "dummy",
    ),
    array(
        "id" => 15123,
        "dummyData123" => "dummy",
        "dummyData5" => "dummy",
        "dummyData1" => "dummy",
        "dummyData494" => "dummy",
        "dummyData5" => "dummy",
        "dummyData3" => "dummy",
        "dummyData6" => "dummy",
    ),
    array(
        "id" => 123,
        "dummyData123" => "dummy",
        "dummyData5" => "dummy",
        "dummyData1" => "dummy",
        "dummyData494" => "dummy",
        "dummyData5" => "dummy",
        "dummyData3" => "dummy",
        "dummyData6" => "dummy",
        ),
);


$mSmallArray = array(

    array(
        "Footage_ID" => 1,
        "dummyData5" => "dummy",
    ),
    array(
        "Footage_ID" => 123,
        "dummyData5" => "dummy",
    ),
    array(
        "Footage_ID" => 0,
        "dummyData5" => "dummy",
        ),
    );


function findElementsThatDontExistFromArrayInArray($mFirstArray, $mSecondArray, $keyToCompareFirstArray, $keyToCompareSecondArray){

    $mFinalArray = null; // Initialize 

    foreach($mFirstArray as $firstArrayCurrent){

        $doesExist = false; // Initialize 

        foreach($mSecondArray as $secondArrayCurrent){


            // Loop through all the elements and if element with the same id - footage_id exist then change the boolean.
            if($firstArrayCurrent[$keyToCompareFirstArray] == $secondArrayCurrent[$keyToCompareSecondArray])
                $doesExist = true;


        }

        if(!$doesExist) // If $doesExist is false, that means it was not found. Add that element to a final array.
            $mFinalArray[] = $firstArrayCurrent;

    }

    return $mFinalArray; // Return it
}


$mFinalArray = findElementsThatDontExistFromArrayInArray($mSmallArray, $mBigArray, "Footage_ID", "id");

print_r($mFinalArray);
```

> Output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Footage_ID] => 0
            [dummyData5] => dummy
        )

)
```

The object (with "Footage_ID" = 0) in `$mSmallArray` doesn't exist in `$mBigArray` (by comparing "id" and "Footage_ID") so it's returned to the final array.

Answer (score 1):

This question is simply solved by using `array_column()` and `array_diff()` because you are only comparing one "column" of values from each array.

Simplified Input and Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/486qV))

```
$footage = [
    ["ID" => "172"],
    ["ID" => "174"],
    ["ID" => "176"],
    ["ID" => "178"],
    ["ID" => "180"]
];
$array2 = [
    ["Footage_ID" => "172"],
    ["Footage_ID" => "173"],
    ["Footage_ID" => "174"],
    ["Footage_ID" => "175"],
    ["Footage_ID" => "176"]
];

var_export(
    array_diff(
        array_column($footage, "ID"),
        array_column($array2, "Footage_ID")
    )
);
```

Output ($footage ID's that are not found in $array2's Footage_ID values):

```
array (
  3 => '178',
  4 => '180',
)
```

*note, you can choose to preserve the keys as in the above output, or you can call `array_values()` on the result array to re-index the keys.

Also be aware that on large data sets you will notice a drag in performance due to making value-based comparisons.  Functions that make value-based comparisons are `array_diff()`, `array_search()`, `in_array()`, and others -- these potentially iterate ALL elements in the haystack array.  Functions that make value-based comparisons do not perform as well as key-based comparisons in php.  To enjoy the performance of `array_diff_key()`, you will need to prepare the inputs in a slightly different fashion -- with temporary first level keys.  This what I'd probably use:

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ACi0T))

```
var_export(
    array_diff_key(
        array_column($footage, null, "ID"),
        array_column($array2, null, "Footage_ID")
    )
);
```

You could also use `array_udiff()` and avoid the preparation of the new keys: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/759K8))

```
var_export(
    array_udiff(
        $footage,
        $array2,
        fn($a, $b) => ($a['Footage_ID'] ?? $a['ID']) <=> ($b['Footage_ID'] ?? $b['ID'])
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

`$secondArray` : Let's suppose is the array with the big data (array #2) of yours.

`$arr1` : Let's suppose is the array with the small data (array #1) of yours.

```
foreach($arr1 as $k=>$v){ 
        $key = array_search($v['ID'], array_column($secondArray, 'Footage_ID')); //if not found in second array, it will return false
        if($key === false){
            $filter_array[] = $v; 
        }
    }
    echo "<pre>12";print_r($filter_array);
```