# Remove elements from a flat array if found in a column of an array of objects

Tags: php, arrays, filtering, array-difference, blacklist

I have a one-dimensional array of values in one array and I need to filter it by a particular property/column in an array of objects.

My input arrays are populated by the following code:

```
$array_one = array_keys(wc_get_account_menu_items());
$array_tow = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT pa_menu_endpoint FROM $phantom_menu WHERE pa_menu_from='pa_custom_tab'");
```

Example data for these arrays:

```
$array_one = [
    'dashboard',
    'orders',
    'downloads',
    'edit-address',
    'woo-wallet',
    'edit-account',
    'customer-logout',
    'test',
    'testtest'
];

$array_tow = [
    (object) ['pa_menu_endpoint' => 'test'],
    (object) ['pa_menu_endpoint' => 'testtest']
];
```

How can I exclude "pa_menu_endpoint" values from the `$array_one` array.

Desired filtered result:

```
[
    'dashboard',
    'orders',
    'downloads',
    'edit-address',
    'woo-wallet',
    'edit-account',
    'customer-logout'
]
```

Comment: Is this what you're after? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

Comment: Please can you do a var_dump() of both $array_one and $array_tow to confirm they have the same structure

Comment: Near duplicate (that does slightly more than required): [PHP - Finding the difference between Two Multidimensional Arrays with different structures based on one value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44027153/2943403)

Comment: Also related, with inverted filtering (intersections instead of differences): [Filter an array of objects by a flat array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62261618/2943403)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter the flat `$array_tow` array by the two dimensional `array_one` array directly using `array_udiff()` and the null coalescing operator in the comparing callback to fallback to the `$array_tow` value when `$a` or `$b` is not an object.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/H7Kd5))

```
var_export(
    array_udiff(
        $array_tow,
        $array_one,
        fn($a, $b) => ($a->pa_menu_endpoint ?? $a) <=> ($b->pa_menu_endpoint ?? $b)
    )
);
```

---

Perhaps simpler to understand will be to pre-flatten the filtering array (`$array_one`) -- this is two function calls, but no custom callbacks.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/5XBss))

```
var_export(
    array_diff(
        $array_tow,
        array_column($array_one, 'pa_menu_endpoint')
    )
);
```

Comment: Sure @mickmackusa, I'll do it. thanks again.

Comment: here you are https://3v4l.org/aXWeg

Comment: @Beh see my commented notes on your script: https://3v4l.org/gRnt3